# DNS (A record) entry not working, ping gives "unknown host"

Tags: domains, dns

I bought a domain and added an A record. The following shows under the "Current Running Records" section.

- Type - A
- Parameter - fash.lk
- Value - 104.131.26.48
- TTL - 86400

But when I try to ping fash.lk I get "unknown host fash.lk". I can ping the IP of the server successfully.

Is there any  more configuration I have to do to get the domain name to point at my server? If not, what tools are there to diagnose the problem and how can I use them?

Comment: Please provide the real domain name. If you want to have a public service (like website) there, then it's not a secret. Also I assume you wait enough time to allow propagation to complete.

Comment: Consider where you are creating the DNS entries. Often people create the DNS records on their web host while the registrar is the statement of authority (SOA) for the domain. If you are creating them in the wrong place, it will not work. Also consider that it can take anywhere from 1-72 hours for the DNS servers to propagate your changes through all of the Internet's DNS servers.

Comment: @Putnik added the domain name

Comment: If you're working inside an active directory environment with the same domain name, you would need to create that A record also in your local DNS server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the DNS server configured at the domain name registrar. Right now the World doesn't know about your domain, it even doesn't know where to ask about it:

```
root@dev2 [~]# dig fash.lk ns +short
root@dev2 [~]#
```

instead you should see something like that:

```
root@dev2 [~]# dig gov.lk ns +short
ns1.gov.lk.
d.nic.lk.
ns2.gov.lk.
c.nic.lk.
m.nic.lk.
root@dev2 [~]#
```

Solution: go to the domain name registrar where you bought it, and configure the name servers. Usually you must create at least two NS (or have two NS records).

Alternatively you can use the NSes of the registrar, please contact support there.

And yes, I assume you did registered(=bought) the domain name, not just configured it :)

Comment: I did buy the domain name :). Can you elaborate one thing for me? There are two options to chose at the registrar's interface. One is to add resource records (I added above A record from there). The other is to add name servers. I thought adding the A record given above was enough. Is it not?

Comment: I see you have done it - because the domain is being resolved properly now :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help though :)